# Can I install Windows (and if so, which one) on my Power Mac G5 tower

Tags: macos, mac, windows, powerpc

Can I install Windows (and if so, which one) on my Power Mac G5 tower? I know the maximum Mac OSX that can be installed is Leopard as I think, so it would be better to run some windows on it. Do you know which one can I install, and what is the maximum version of Windows for it? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtual PC was a software emulator for creating & running Windows virtual machines on Mac systems using the PPC architecture. If you can find it, it'll do what you want albeit at a glacial level of response.

Answer (score 1):

No version of Windows can be installed on a PowerPC platform.  Windows was never compiled for the [RISC architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing).

However, you can install [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/platforms/ppc.html).  I successfully installed FreeBSD on an XServe G4 (using a USB flash disk).